# Creating symlink in /usr/bin when creating an RPM

Tags: rpm

I'm creating an RPM for an application that doesn't already have one.  I've got it building and installing fine in the `/opt` directory using `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT`, but I would also like to create a couple symlinks in `/usr/bin` so that the application is available on the path.  All of my attempts to do this have yielded "permission denied" errors because I'm running `rpmbuild` as a non-root user and it's not allowed to create files in `/usr/bin/`.

Here's my current .spec file:

```
Summary: Berkeley UPC
Name: berkeley_upc
Version: 2.8.0
Release: 1
Source0: %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
License: GPL
Group: Development/Tools
BuildRoot: %{_builddir}/%{name}-root
Prefix: /opt/bupc2.8
Prefix: /usr

%description
Berkeley UPC on the BASS for the comp633 class.

%prep
%setup -q

%build
./configure CC=gcc44 CXX=g++44 --disable-aligned-segments --prefix=/opt/bupc2.8
make %{_smp_mflags}

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
make DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT install

mkdir -p ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_bindir}
mkdir -p ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_mandir}/man1

ln -sf /opt/bupc2.8/bin/upcc          ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_bindir}
ln -sf /opt/bupc2.8/bin/upcc_multi    ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_bindir}
ln -sf /opt/bupc2.8/bin/upcc_multi.pl ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_bindir}
ln -sf /opt/bupc2.8/bin/upcdecl       ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_bindir}
ln -sf /opt/bupc2.8/bin/upcrun        ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_bindir}
ln -sf /opt/bupc2.8/bin/upc_trace     ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_bindir}

ln -sf /opt/bupc2.8/man/man1/upcc.1      ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_mandir}/man1
ln -sf /opt/bupc2.8/man/man1/upcdecl.1   ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_mandir}/man1
ln -sf /opt/bupc2.8/man/man1/upcrun.1    ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_mandir}/man1
ln -sf /opt/bupc2.8/man/man1/upc_trace.1 ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_mandir}/man1

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/opt/bupc2.8
%config /opt/bupc2.8/etc
%config /opt/bupc2.8/opt/etc

%{_bindir}/upcc
%{_bindir}/upcc_multi
%{_bindir}/upcc_multi.pl
%{_bindir}/upcdecl
%{_bindir}/upcrun
%{_bindir}/upc_trace

%{_mandir}/man1/upcc.1.gz
%{_mandir}/man1/upcdecl.1.gz
%{_mandir}/man1/upcrun.1.gz
%{_mandir}/man1/upc_trace.1.gz
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ln -sf /opt/bupc2.8/bin/upcc ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/%{_bindir}`

The link needs to be created in the `%build` section and it also needs to point to where you're *installing* the RPM.

Before creating the link  make sure that the destination directory exists, i.e. `${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/%{_bindir}`. You can use `mkdir` or `install -d` for this.

Comment: I edited my .spec file according to what I think you suggested and I'm getting the following error:
+ ln -sf /opt/bupc2.8/bin/upcc /home/eddale/src/rpm/tmp/berkeley_upc-root/usr/bin
ln: creating symbolic link `/home/eddale/src/rpm/tmp/berkeley_upc-root/usr/bin' to `/opt/bupc2.8/bin/upcc': No such file or directory

Comment: I think that you need to create the destination directory, i.e. `/home/.../usr/bin`. Here's how I do it: http://github.com/ciupicri/rpmbuild/blob/master/SPECS/python-trml2pdf.spec#L36 (line 36).

Comment: That was the problem. I've updated the question to contain the final working version.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`macro %{__ln_s}` is good also

example add symbolic link post install:

```
%post
%{__ln_s} -f %{_bindir}/exec %{_bindir}/exec2
```

example remove symbolic link uninstall:

```
%postun
case "$1" in
  0) # last one out put out the lights
    rm -f %{_bindir}/exec2
  ;;
esac
```

The `case` statement ensures that the file is only removed on uninstall, and not upgrade, downgrade, or reinstall. RPM `%postun` for the old package runs *after* `%post` for the new package (even if that's the same version).

Comment: During an rpm -U upgrade, the old rpm will execute the %postun and destroy that file. The new rpm will not have a link, your code is bad.

Comment: @ljdelight - This was trivial to fix - 5 years down the road.